# hotspots not linking in product viewer

Tags: javascript, html, ios, jquery-mobile

So using a script for 360 image rotation, i've set up a tags to act as hot spots and lead to different pages within a jquery mobile document. Everything works a desktop, but when i test the page on an ipad, none of the links do anywhere. Heres the script for the rotation.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $product = $('#product'),
        $imgs = $product.find(".child"),
        imageTotal = $imgs.length - 1,
        clicked = false,
        widthStep = 4,
        currPos,
        currImg = 0,
        lastImg = 0;
    $imgs.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent dragging images
    })
        .filter(':gt(0)').addClass('notseen');

    $product.bind('mousedown touchstart', function (e) {
        if (e.type == "touchstart") {
            currPos = window.event.touches[0].pageX;
        } else {
            currPos = e.pageX;
        }
        clicked = true;
        return false;
    });
    $(document)
        .bind('mouseup touchend', function () {
        clicked = false;
    })
        .bind('mousemove touchmove', function (e) {
        if (clicked) {
            var pageX;
            if (e.type == "touchmove") {
                pageX = window.event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
            } else {
                pageX = e.pageX;
            }
            widthStep = 4;
            if (Math.abs(currPos - pageX) >= widthStep) {
                if (currPos - pageX >= widthStep) {
                    currImg++;
                   if (currImg > imageTotal) {
  currImg = 0;
}
                } else {
                    currImg--;
                    if (currImg < 1) {
                        currImg = imageTotal;
                    }
                }
                currPos = pageX;
                $imgs.eq(lastImg).addClass('notseen');
                $imgs.eq(currImg).removeClass('notseen');
                lastImg = currImg;
                // $obj.html('<img src="' + aImages[options.currImg] + '" />');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm know its the script because when i remove it, the links work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(document).ready()` is not supported in jQM.

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/faq/dom-ready-not-working.php